# Bootstrap 3 When clicking dropdown menu navbar-collapse is closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic Bootstrap 3 responsive nav like so:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0" data-target="#navbar-main">
    <div id="navbar-main">
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span
                            class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>brand</strong></a></div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">page-1</a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">page-1-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page-1-2</a></li>
                          </ul>
                   </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click the dropdown menu button in collapsed mode, navbar is closing and I cannot see the dropdown menu.

When I open nav:
[image]

and clicked Page-1:
[image]

It should open a dropdown menu below Page 1 but when I click Page-1 it closes nav. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe a running example?

Comment: **[Works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fjthmwj3/)**... The issue might be because of some other `scripts` or `css`, which we cannot identify with current piece of code.. Better try to replicate in `jsfiddle` so that we can have look into it..

Comment: I am using
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: What happens if you change a href="#" to something it can direct to, like www.google.com, does it still do the same thing?